# Nested If Statements in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Hi I am having trouble running the following Nested if statement in an SSRS expression

```
= SUM(IIF(UCASE(TRIM(Fields!UOP.Value))="Y", IIF(UCASE(TRIM(Fields!HED.Value))="Y",
  IIF(UCASE(TRIM(Fields!FROMB.Value))="RED",
IIF(UCASE(TRIM(Fields!TOB.Value))="BLUE",1,0),0),0))
```

Not sure if my parentheses are in the right position or not....

Basically I want to find a sum total of the expression only if all if statements are true and has the above values else not.

Comment: an alternative to nested if statements would be appreciated too if possible...thanks

Comment: What is your trouble? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes i am...it says wrong number of arguments...i can't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's dissect your statement:

```
=SUM(
    IIF(UCASE(TRIM(Fields!UOP.Value))="Y", 
        IIF(UCASE(TRIM(Fields!HED.Value))="Y",
            IIF(UCASE(TRIM(Fields!FROMB.Value))="RED",
                IIF(UCASE(TRIM(Fields!TOB.Value))="BLUE",
                    1,
                    0),
            0),
        0)
    )
```

Your parentheses are unbalanced, and you are missing the *false* argument for the first `IIF`.

Alternatively, you can invert your conditions and use `SWITCH` instead, which would be a bit easier to read:

```
=SUM(Switch( _
    UCASE(TRIM(Fields!UOP.Value))<>"Y", UOPFalseValue, _
    UCASE(TRIM(Fields!HED.Value))<>"Y", 0, _
    UCASE(TRIM(Fields!FROMB.Value))<>"RED", 0, _
    UCASE(TRIM(Fields!TOB.Value))<>"BLUE", 0, _
    True, 1))
```

Or, since it appears your *false* value is always 0, you can just combine the conditions using `And`:

```
=SUM(IIF(And(And(And(UCASE(TRIM(Fields!UOP.Value))="Y", _
    UCASE(TRIM(Fields!HED.Value))"Y"), _
    UCASE(TRIM(Fields!FROMB.Value))="RED"), _
    UCASE(TRIM(Fields!TOB.Value))="BLUE"), 1, 0))
```

Comment: Could you suggest an improved answer?